# list is being destroyed when using decorator

Tags: python

In the code below, I use a decorator to perform changes on class variables

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self):
        self.vars = [1,2]
        self.log = None

    def _mydecorator(function):
        def logger(self):
            self.log = "BLA"
            function(self)
        return logger

    @_mydecorator
    def addone(self):
        print("Inside Class: %s" % map(lambda x: x+1, self.vars))
        return map(lambda x: x+1, self.vars)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myclass = MyClass()
    print myclass.addone()
```

This script returns:

```
Inside Class: [2,3]
None
```

Why are the values not passed to the caller?

If I do not decorate the `addone` function I get:

```
Inside Class: [2,3]
[2,3]
```

What does this decorator change?

Comment: Your `logger` is not returning the value of the wrapped function.  You need to do `return function(self)`.

Comment: Aside: if you're experimenting with decorators, don't forget to look at [`functools.wraps`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps), which lets decorated functions resemble the undecorated ones a little more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change your decorator to return the result of invoking the undecorated method:

```
def _mydecorator(function):
    def logger(self):
        self.log = "BLA"
        return function(self)
    return logger
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `logger` function doesn't return the result of the function call. Change:

```
function(self)
```

To:

```
return function(self)
```